# Can't download a font using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I can't download a font using webpack. I get constantly the following message in console:
Failed to decode downloaded font

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/i,
    use: ['csv-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.xml$/i,
    use: ['xml-loader'],
  },
],
```

},
mode: 'development'};

[image]

can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the parsing rules for the fonts, the configuration example is as follows.

```js
{
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 4096,
              esModule: false,
              fallback: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: 'fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                  esModule: false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```